# Short Gamma Ray Bursts from black hole mergers

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, gamma-rays

I have read in passing that short gamma ray bursts can be caused by the merger of 2 black holes in a binary system.

I have Googled but can't seem to find any good sources describing the phenomenon and the mathematics.

Can anyone provide information and the associated mathematics on this effect?

Comment: You're probably using the wrong words in your search because Googling `BH-BH merger GRB` gave me *lots* of resources. You probably could get more hits if you replaced "BH-BH" with "double compact."

Comment: There seems to be a lot of material on compact object binary mergers (neutron star/blackhole or neutron star/neutron star), and investigation if the SGRB is from a black hole that results from NS/NS binary merger.  Here's an example: http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.06791. Would these interest you?

Answer (score 0):

After some research led by the comments to the question, the most comprehensive, up-to-date source I've found is http://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.0679v1.pdf. I hope this helps others.